# iOS SDK cache not working as expected

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, caching, sdk

I tried to use iOS built in NSURLCache, but it's not smart and sometimes it tries to read data from net, instead of local cache, for example when there is net, but slow.

Anyway, is there any perfect library for caching web data ( html & images) for iOS which works seamlessly?

Thanks!

Comment: AFnetworking or SDwebImages is best sdk for doing this type of task

Comment: AFnetworking  uiimageview category is good

Comment: @NitinGohel, AFNetworking uses built-in cache, which I don't prefer: Does AFNetworking have any caching mechanisms built-in?
AFNetworking takes advantage of the caching functionality already provided by NSURLCache and any of its subclasses. So long as your NSURLRequest objects have the correct cache policy, and your server response contains a valid Cache-Control header, responses will be automatically cached for subsequent requests.

Comment: try with https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @NitinGohel As OS docs mention, NSCache is not permanent, but I need to be permanent.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you don't know about this great library [`ASIHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

Comment: Its great but currently not being maintained and have faced issues in iPOD1+ios6 combination. AFNetworking is good